# Linear function applied to sides of rectangle and its tiles

Tags: linear-algebra, tiling

I'm trying to follow miniature 12 in [Thirty-three Miniatures: Mathematical
and Algorithmic Applications of
Linear Algebra](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf) where Matousek proves that it isn't possible to tile a rectangle the ratio of whose side are irrational with a square. Towards the end of the proof, he defines a linear function, $f(x)$. Consider now a rectangle, $R$ with sides $a$ and $b$. He defines the function $v(R)=f(a)f(b)$. It is then claimed that if a set of smaller rectangles, $Q_i$ (with side $a_i$ and $b_i$) tile the rectangle, we must have:

$$v(R) = \sum_i v(Q_i)$$

And this is because the function $f$ is linear. To me, this seems obviously off. Let's consider that the function $f$ is $f(x)=x$. This is a linear function. Now, the equation above suggests:

$$a b = \sum_i a_i b_i $$

But because of the requirement of tiling, we also have:

$$a=\sum_i a_i$$ and
$$b = \sum_i b_i$$

This obviously isn't correct since there will be cross-terms. What am I missing?

Comment: If for example you have four 1x1 rectangles tiling a larger rectangle, that does not mean that the larger rectangle is 1+1+1+1 by 1+1+1+1. Your sums for a and b do not follow from the tiling requirement. The tiling requirement instead means that the sum of the areas of the smaller rectangles is equal to the area of the larger rectangle.

Comment: You're mixing up your letters. You've defined $v(A)$ without defining $A$. But it looks like if $f(x)=x$ then $v(J)$ is just the area of $J$ for any rectangle $J$. So the formula you criticize just says the area of a big rectangle equals the sum of the areas of the rectangle that tile it. What's wrong is your $a=\sum a_i$ and $b=\sum b_i$.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, Rohit? (I see you edited $A$ to $R$, which is good.)

Comment: Yes, that solves this question. That was a bad miss on my part. I'm still stuck on another part of the proof which I'm going to ask a different question for. Since there isn't an answer here, I can't accept or do anything else to establish closure, right?

Comment: You can write up an answer, now that you understand the situation. It's good practice for writing stuff up. You can even accept your own answer.

Comment: Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, this was a bad miss on my part. I assumed that for a tiling, we required $a=\sum_i a_i$ and $b = \sum_i b_i$. This is certainly not the case as the simple counter-example below shows. The sum of the sides of the four squares that tile the larger square is 4 while the side length of the larger square is only 2.

However, I'm still stuck on the proof itself at another place which I've asked a different question for: [Product of linear function applied to the two sides of a rectangle is supposed to equate to the sum across its tiles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241254/product-of-linear-function-applied-to-the-two-sides-of-a-rectangle-is-supposed-t)

[image]