# Product of linear function applied to the two sides of a rectangle is supposed to equate to the sum across its tiles.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

**Background**

I'm trying to follow miniature 12 in [Thirty-three Miniatures: Mathematical
and Algorithmic Applications of
Linear Algebra](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf) where Matousek proves that it isn't possible to tile a rectangle the ratio of whose side are irrational with a square. In order to do this, he applies a linear function, $f$ that maps a set $V$ to the set of real numbers, $\Bbb R$. I don't think its important for now what $V$ is, but you can always get the definition from the PDF linked above. This function is to have the following properties:

1. $f(1)=1$
2. $f(x)=-1$, where $x$ is some irrational number greater than zero.

Now for a rectangle $A$ with sides $a$ and $b$, a new function is defined:

$$v(A) = f(a)f(b)$$

Now, if the rectangle $A$ is partitioned into smaller rectangles, $B_i$ that completely tile it, it is claimed that:

$$v(A) = \sum_i v(B_i) \tag{1}$$

---

**Where I'm stuck**

Let's consider first that $f(y)=y$. Then, $v(A)$ just becomes the area of the rectangle and equation (1) above obviously holds pretty much by definition (if the smaller rectangles tile the larger one, the sum of their areas should equal that of the larger one).

Now, let's consider $f(y) = \mu y$. This is equivalent to making $v(A)$ the area of the rectangle in some different units. So, equation (1) above still holds by the same area argument.

Finally, we make $f$ as general as possible while still keeping it linear. This gives us: $f(y) = \mu y + \nu$. And at this point, the result seems to no longer hold. Consider a very simple case of a square of side $2$ tiled by four squares each of side $1$ (figure below). Also, consider the function $f(y)=y+1$. For the larger square, we get:

$$v(A) = (2+1)(2+1)=9$$

And for each of the small squares $B_i$ we get:

$$v(B_i) = (1+1)(1+1) = 4$$

And there are four such squares, so $\sum v(B_i) = 16 \neq 9 = v(A)$.

Hence, the result seems to fail to hold. Now, maybe Matousek is only considering functions of the form $f(y)=\mu y$. But the two requirements in the background section won't be satisfied necessarily if we add that additional requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you and the author are using two different meaning of the word, "linear".

You are using it in the analytic geometry sense of $f(x)=ax+b$.

The author is using it in the linear algebra sense of $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, and $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$ for all vectors $x$ and all scalars $\alpha$. And in this application, we're considering the reals as a vector space over the rationals, so $x$ is real and $\alpha$ is restricted to being rational.

Comment: Thanks. In the proof, $1$ and $x$ are scalars and he requires $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=-1$ where $x$ is a fixed, positive irrational number. In your definition, setting $\alpha=0$ yields $f(0)=0$. This seems to be impossible given $0<1$ and $0<x$. What am I missing?

Comment: I think $1$ and $x$ are real numbers, hence, *vectors* over the field of rationals, not scalars. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars, that is, rationals, then by linearity $f(\alpha+\beta x)=\alpha f(1)+\beta f(x)=\alpha-\beta$.

Comment: I'm lost here. $1$ and $x$ are vectors over the field of rationals.. what does this mean? How can we get a linear function such that $f(1)=1$, $f(x)=-1$ and $f(0)=0$ are simultaneously satisfied? What does such a function look like? Can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Do you know what a field is? The definition of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is that it's a set whose elements we call vectors such that if you add two vectors you get a vector, and if you multiply a vector by an element of $F$ (which element we call a scalar) you get a vector, and various axioms like associativity and commutativity and distributivity and existence of neutral element and existence of additive inverses hold. The first vector spaces you meet in classes, the field of scalars is the reals, and the vectors are elements of 2- or 3-dimensional Euclidean space (continued)

Comment: (continued) but there are lots of other fields and lots of other vector spaces. The rational numbers form a field, and the real numbers form a vector space over the rationals. If you add two reals, you get a real, and if you multiply a real by a rational, you get a real, and all the vector space axioms alluded to in the previous comment hold. If $x$ is a real irrational, then $1$ and $x$ are linearly independent over the rationals (this is truly just a restatement of the definition of *irrational*), so you can have a linear transformation $f$ from the reals to the reals (continued)

Comment: which takes $1$ to any real you like, and takes $x$ to any real you like; in particular, you can have $f(1)=1$ and $f(x)=-1$. Then for any rationals $\alpha,\beta$ you get $f(\alpha+\beta x)=\alpha-\beta$, as shown earlier. What $f(y)$ is for $y$ not of the form $\alpha+\beta x$ is another story entirely; defining $f$ in its entirety requires high-powered stuff like the Axiom of Choice. But we don't need to know $f(y)$ for such $y$, not for this problem – it's enough to know such an $f$ exists.